# How to map complex types using jackson's mixin?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, moxy, jaxb2

Let's say I have these pojos:

```
    public class Person()
    {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastLamel
        private Address address;

        // setters, getters, toString...
    }

    public class Address()
    {
        private String line1;
        private String city;

        // setters, getters, toString...
    }
```

We can easily serialize the following json:

```
    {
        "firstName":"John"
        "lastName":"Smith"
        "address" : {
            "line" : "Fake Street",
            "city" : "Fake town"
        }
    }
```

Now, let's say, that in addition to the above json, I also need to serialize objects from an XML that has a completely different structure:

```
    <r00t>
        <PrsInfo>
            <frNm>John</fnNm>
            <lNm>Smith</lNm>
        </PrsInfo>
        <lctn>
            <addr>
                <ln>Fake Street</ln>
                <town>Fake town</town>
            </addr>
        </lctn>
    </r00t>
```

Now, first I considered a [MOXy](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy), because you can define bindings in an [external file](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html#). Though, I had a feeling it would be weird to have MOXy with Jackson. Then, I looked into Jackson Mix-Ins. Mixins require to have an abstract class (or an interface) containing mapping instructions, so PersonMixIn and AddressMixIn. For my case, as I understood it, I would have to make copies of the pojos to act as proxy between weirdly-structured xml. That is, I'm trying to avoid having Person, PersonMixin, Address, AddressMixin etc., as it seems a bit of an overkill for a task I'm trying to accomplish + it will be very messy if you have more than two pojos to serialize.

Is there a way for me to have a single PersonMixIn class and map that xml (with an address) ?